# Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Facebook chatbot on Heroku but I'm getting this error:

```
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286607+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286618+00:00 app[web.1]: at parseConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:298:13)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286620+00:00 app[web.1]: at parseHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:129:14)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286622+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:25:12)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286623+00:00 app[web.1]: at deprecated (internal/util.js:67:15)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286625+00:00 app[web.1]: at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:195:3)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286626+00:00 app[web.1]: at connectOp (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:284:3)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286628+00:00 app[web.1]: at executeOperation (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:416:24)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286630+00:00 app[web.1]: at MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:169:10)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286631+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:335:22)
2019-03-26T01:34:39.286633+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout.connectToMongo [as _onTimeout] (/app/index.js:37:14)
```

I have used very simple password, but it still shows same error. How can I fix it?

I'm temporarily using `01234567890` as my password. When I put it into my connection string I get something like

```
mongodb+srv://myuser:<01234567890>@host.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

Comment: What's the password? You can always change it.

Comment: thank you for reply, i use this pw: 01234567890

the config file is here: https://github.com/ngxson/chatbot-cnh/blob/master/custom/const.js#L15

and connection string: mongodb+srv://myuser:<01234567890>@cluster0-kuixy.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true

Answer (score 14):

Try using this approach -

```js
var username = encodeURIComponent("YOUR_DATABASE_USERNAME");
var password = encodeURIComponent("YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD");

var connectionString = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@YOUR_CONNECTION_ENDPOINT`;

var databaseConnection = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString, {
    ssl: true,
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Your connection string shouldn't contain `<` and `>` characters unless they're part of a value in the string (and if they are they may need to be escaped). It's common to see placeholders surrounded by these characters in documentation, but when you replace the placeholder you should remove those characters too.

Try changing your connection string to

```
mongodb+srv://myuser:01234567890@host.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

Once you've confirmed that this works you should immediately change your credentials and any other real database information that you may have posted here.

Comment: How would you escape the character? From reading your answer, I just figured out my error was that I had a `#` in my password. So, how would I escape the `#`? Thanks

Comment: @TheProCoder, I believe [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it will work. `#` would become `%23`.