# why mongoose is not connecting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

node "c:\Users\muham\Coading 1\WEB DEVELOPMENT\MERN\SOCIAL-APP\server\index.js"
MongoParseError: Password contains unescaped characters did not connect
(node:7812) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

i had done with every steps ut still it's showing linke this

Comment: 'Password contains unescaped characters did not connect' - I would start there or give us more information to go off. Like the code you use to connect to mongoose

Comment: Welcome! Similar problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348695/error-password-contains-an-illegal-unescaped-character